# Boostrap Styling Tabletools is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, tabletools

The output in Chrome and Firefox is different. When in Chrome, I was able to see all the button but it doesn't work. In Firefox just the print button.

What's the problem here? I just follow the example in their documentation.
Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/j0gkjr2o/4/).

I am using AJAX to get the data from my server, just a snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'tbl/',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(s) {
         //alert(s.length);
         tbl_barangay.fnClearTable();
         for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
             tbl_barangay.fnAddData([
                 s[i]['loc'],
                 s[i]['countlow'] || 0,
                 s[i]['countmedium'] || 0,
                 s[i]['counthigh'] || 0
             ]);
         }
     },
     error: function(e) {
         alert(e.responseText);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Make sure your flash is enabled, working and not being blocked by a script blocker. Tabletools does not play well with Firefox or IE. Chrome is the only browser it seems to work out of the box in.

Comment: I think tabletools works great with IE, FF, Safari and Opera also, but especially IE-users using IIS seems to have problems (with relative paths). I also think this question is a pure "flash is blocked"-problem.

Comment: Actually no, I tried the examples from the site and it works.